# VS2010 use project references or link to library?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, linker, dependencies, googletest

**SUMMARY**:

***What is references for in VS2010 ? When do you use references and when do you use the Add Depencies in Linker section of the properties?***

**DETAILS**:
In VS2010, I have one solution containing two projects. In the second project, i have one class defining instances of classes from the first project. Also, the first project integrates some DLL, and is linked in VS to the library corresponding to this DLL.

To have the second project compile, at first, I proceed as follows.

- Link the second project to the library included in the first project
- build the first project into a LIB
- link the second project to the lib that i have just generated

This is compiling ok. But for some reason, this solution is not possible for me (i am using the generated DLL, for the second project, to run test from command line ; when the second project is linked to a lib for the first project and indirectly to the lib embedded in first project, i struggle to run the test)

So, i thought of, in second project

- delete the link to the lib for the first project
- delete the link to the lib for the library included in first project
- add a reference to the first project (Project > References > Add New Reference)
- add a Project Dependencies pf first project towards the second project

This is not compiling.

Errors are link errors LNK2001 involving a lot of Qt lexicon. Let's add that classes from first project which source code have to be accessed by methods in second project are Q_OBJECT macroed.

***1/ Do you have a hint ?***

***2/ What is references for in VS2010 ? When do you use references and when do you use the Add Depencies in Linker section of the properties?***